# Reading data from text file and pass the data to Login method

Tags: c#, selenium, text-files

I'm new to coding and I'm writing a test automation framework for a local Wordpress setup and I want to use a text file to store username, password, xpaths etc. I have a class where I want to handle the reading of the data from the text file and pass the data to a login method. It looks like this:

Reading the data:

```
public class CSV
{
    public string username;
    public string password;

    public void ReadCsvFile()
    {            

        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(@"Textfile.txt");


        while (!reader.EndOfStream)
            {
                var line = reader.ReadLine();
                var values = line.Split(',');                    

                username = values[1];
                password = values[2];

            }


    }
}
```

Method that I pass the username to:

```
public void Login()
    {        

        var usernameField = Driver.Instance.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[contains(@id, 'user_login')]"));
        usernameField.SendKeys(username);
```

When running the Login test I get an error saying "Text cannot be null" which i guess means that my variable username is pointing to nothing.

Comment: Use the debugger force, Luke

Answer (score 0):

Without having an IDE and run it with you, here are some thing to check.

1. I'm assuming that the error was thrown when you call the line
   userNamefield.sendKey. Is that correct?
2. Make sure that By.XPath("//input[contains(@id, 'user_login')]") does
   return something so that Driver.Instance.FindElement can operate.
3. To verify if username is pointing to nothing, just put a breakpoint
   on that line and hover your cursor over the variable. The IDE will
   show you what is the username variable.

Let me know what you find, maybe I can help.

Comment: Thank you for answering! 

1. Yes that´s correct. The error point to that specific line of code. 

2. The XPath works fine. If I put the login credentials in a seperate class in a property the test works. 

3. When hovering, it points to "(field) string CVS.username". 
If I right click username and select Find all references, it points to "username = values[1]" in the CSV class (not sure if Find all references is the correct thing to use here). 

The txt file I´m using is just two lines with the username and password in the top rows. It´s stored in the project folder and in VS.

Comment: instead of using By.XPath("//input[contains(@id,'user_login'))]"), replace it with By.Id("user_login")

Comment: Ok why should I use Id? Does that help me in my current issue I have? I’ve tried that to and works just like the XPath. Thanks for your comment!

Answer (score 0):

From what you have posted, I'm guessing the problem is that you are reading `username` and `password` from the CSV class but those values never get passed back to the main script so they can be passed to your `Login()` function. Another issue is that you aren't passing any values into your `Login()` function... you should be passing in `username` and `password`.

There are several ways to handle reading a CSV.

1. One way would be to read it a line at a time and pass back `username` and `password` for that line. This is better for larger files since it saves memory.
2. Another way would be to read the entire file and return a collection of values that include `username` and `password`.

Comment: Alright thanks for the input! You have any tip on how I should read it a line at the time and pass it back? Thought I was kind of doing that with the Readline method.

Comment: One way (#1 in my answer) is to take the code that you have in `ReadCsvFile()` and put that in your main script file. Right after you store `username` and `password` your script starts. Then you change `Login()` to `Login(string username, string password)` and pass in what you read from the file.

Comment: Thanks I´ll try it! The only problem I see with that is that my original plan to have a class that takes care of the reading of the file so I don´t have to put the same code for each test, is not useful anymore. But maybe that´s the best way to go here.